# does an analytic function have a bounded derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a domain and $f : G \to G$ be any holomorphic function that satisfies $f(z_0) = w_0$ for $z_0, w_0 \in G$. Must it be the case that $|f'(z_0)|$ is uniformly bounded?

When $G$ is the open unit disk this is a result of the pick lemma. Does this generalize to arbitrary domains? I thought about composing $f$ with with mobius transforms to try and apply the pick lemma, but I could not think of any that would work since $G$ need not contain the open unit disk.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Let us know what you have thought about this Q. It will help us provide hints / solution

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. Is that really what you intended to ask?

Comment: @zhw I have edited the question to clarify what I meant

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you mean is $|f'(z_0)|$ uniformly bounded as $f$ varies over all such functions.

Comment: @mrf yes, I believe so. What I mean is that is there a constant $C$ such that $|f'(z_0)| \leq C$ for any $f$ that satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true in general. Take $G = \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z) = z^n$. Then $f(1) = 1$ for all $n$ but $f'(1) = n$.

If $G$ is bounded, everything is fine. By Cauchy's integral formula:
$$
f'(z_0) = \frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^2}\,d\zeta
$$
where $\gamma$ is for example a small circle of radius $r$ in $G$ surrounding $z_0$. Hence:
$$
|f'(z_0)| \le \frac1{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi r \cdot \max_{\zeta \in \gamma} \left| \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^2} \right| \le \frac{M}{r}
$$
independently of $f$. (Here $M$ is a number such that $|z| \le M$ for all $z\in G$.)

Comment: Is it necessary that $G$ is bounded, or is $G = \mathbb{C}$ the only time this will fail?

Comment: @user229365 It's not the only counterexample. Take $G = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $f_n(z) = \exp(n(z-1))$ and $z_0 = w_0 = 1$. But if $G$ is contained in a simply connected domain that is not $\mathbb{C}$, you can use Riemann's mapping theorem to transform everything to the bounded case.

Comment: @mrw I see. So then we take the unique biholomorphic map $g$ that sends $G$ to the unit disk with $g(w_0) = 0, g'(w_0) > 0$, and then apply the above argument to $(g \circ f)$, correct?

Comment: @mrf Have you explicitly assume that $f(\xi) \leq M$. If so, did you infer this inequality by assuming that the domain, $G$, is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @JunaidAftab $f$ was assumed to be $G \to G$ with $G$ bounded.

Comment: @mrf Oh. I assumed that natural condition to impose on $G$ would be to assume that $G$ is compact. This condition also allows one to infer the conclusion, though.